# Angular 6: Detect if a form with async pipe has actual changes

Tags: angular

With Angular 6, I have a form where the data comes from an Observable via an async pipe:

```
<div class="header">
  <button (click)="leave()">Leave</button>
</div>
<div *ngIf="car$ | async as car">
  <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(car)">
    <label>Make: <input type="text" name="make" [(ngModel)]="car.make"></label>
    <label>Model: <input type="text" name="model" [(ngModel)]="car.model"></label>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

When calling the `onSubmit()` function of the controller I provide the local variable `car` as a parameter. In this way I have the actual values and I can update the data store, for example through a web service.

I also have a `canDeactivate()` guard. If the user navigates away form the page, for example through the "Leave" button, I want to check if the data in the form has been changed.

I know I can check if the form is dirty with the following code:

```
@ViewChild('form') form: NgForm;
...
canDeactivate() {
  if (this.form.dirty) { ... }
}
```

If the user enters or deletes some text, `dirty` will be `true`. However this does not mean the actual values are different from the original values.

To determine if the values have actually changed, I want to compare the actual values to the original values. I can store the original values by `tap()`-ing into the Observable. But how do I access the actual values inside `canDeactivate`?

Or perhaps there is another solution?

Comment: Why is your ngModel set as car? If you can create another property in your component.ts, call it say actualValue, then on canDeactivate you can check if car.make === actualValue.make and so on

Comment: Don't you think you should be using Reactive Forms instead of Template Driven forms for this use case?

Comment: @VinodBhavnani Not sure what you mean. `car` is my async pipe local variabele. That's why I have to use it in the form. And I cannot access this local variable in my controller. That's exactly my problem.

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera Perhaps. I am not familiar with reactive forms (coming from AngularJS). Can you show in an example how this will solve my problem?